# php - html: Different data in each row of a the same column in a table

Tags: php, html, dynamic, row

I want to make a cell's data different in each row of the same column, according to the value of the $row['epilogh']:

```
<tr>
    <td> <?php echo $row['id']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['epilogh']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['um_username']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['myrole'];?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['request_date'];?> </td>

    <!-- i want the following 2 td to be one and work in the above different cases  -->
    <td style="max-width: 250px; text-align: center;">
    <?php echo '<a href="../make-solemn-declaration-pdf-sec/?id='.$row['id'].'" target="_blank">'.$row['id'].'</a>';?>
                                <form action="../make-solemn-declaration-pdf/?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="POST" target="_blank">
                                    <button type="submit" name="btn-pdf">Make a PDF</button>
    </form>
    </td>

    <td style="max-width: 250px">  
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="../upload-file/?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept=".pdf" required />
            <br><hr>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
            <? echo "$pdf";?>
        </form>
    </td>

    <td> <a href="../pistop-delete/?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a> </td>
</tr>
```

So let's say that if `$row['epilogh']` is 'A' I want a form so a file could be uploaded. On the other hand when `$row['epilogh']` is 'B' I want to have a link there for another page. How can I do this?

Comment: You could do it in PHP or MySQL. In MySQL you could construct with a `case when` statement. In PHP you could just use an `if` or chained `if`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand you correctly, you can do this:
just use one td:

```
<td style="max-width: 250px;<?php if($row['epilogh'] == 'A')  echo 'text-align: center;' ?> ">
 <?php
   if($row['epilogh'] == 'A'){
     echo "your upload form"
   }
   else{
     echo "your link to another page"
   }
?>
</td>
```

Comment: Yes as i see you understand correctly, but i already tried this and it wasn't working because i had a silly mistake! Thank you very much though because with your example i understood it and saw it!

Comment: glad to know you understood the problem. if this is your answer then consider choosing it as the correct answer. thanks @Scissors38th

Comment: i just missed the double equals in the if clause. i was wondering the whole day but you know... when your head sticks sometimes you cant see the obvious!